# Apply a Oil Paint/Sketch effect to a photo using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, filter, photo

I want to simulate an human drawing effect starting from a photo, using javascript.

I've been searching trough several js libraries that do image manipulation (mostly on canvas). 
But seems that no one even attempted what I'm looking for.

[image: photoshop oil paint filter]

I don't think it's impossible to achieve such effects with javascript. So I wonder why I can't find anything already done.

On the native side there are several alternatives to photoshop to achieve such effects, as seen in several apps in the App Store:

- [Oil Painting Booth Free](https://itunes.apple.com/it/app/oil-painting-booth-free-best/id486172126?mt=8)
- [Brushstroke](http://www.pastemagazine.com/articles/2014/03/brushstroke-app-turns-your-photos-into-lovely-pain.html)
- [Autopainter](https://itunes.apple.com/IT/app/id429133097?mt=8)
- [Artist's Touch](https://itunes.apple.com/IT/app/id298606069?mt=8)
- [Autographo](https://itunes.apple.com/IT/app/id442567684?mt=8)

Here's other examples of possible result (from Artist's Touch App):

[image: Artist's Touch App]

Comment: If its not done in JS you need to start searching for the algorithms used for this effect and implement them on your own.

Comment: Of course so. But even if the examples I found weren't built already, so good luck guessing the algorithm, this question is a tentative to avoid that. I'm hoping I missed some library, or plugin for existing libraries.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Alright so I found a great explanation of the algorithm used **[here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/471994/OilPaintEffect)** and adapted it to JS and canvas.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/96arS/)**

**[CodePen Demo with controls to mess with the effect](http://codepen.io/loktar00/full/Fhzot/)**

[image: effect result]

How it works is you average all the pixels around your center pixel, then you multiply that average by the intensity level you want, you then divide it by 255. Then you increment the r/g/b's related to the intensity level. Then you check which intensity level was most common among the pixels neighbors, and assign the target pixel that intensity level.

**edit** worked on it a bit more and rewrote a lot of it, gained some really huge performance gains, works with decent sized images now pretty well.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"),
    img = new Image();

img.addEventListener('load', function () {
    canvas.width = this.width;
    canvas.height = this.height;
    ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    oilPaintEffect(canvas, 4, 55);
});

img.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";
img.src = "https://fbcdn-sphotos-h-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpa1/v/t1.0-9/1379992_10202357787410559_1075078295_n.jpg?oh=5b001e9848796dd942f47a0b2f3df6af&oe=542F3FEF&__gda__=1412145968_4dbb7f75b385770ecc3f4b88105cb0f8";

function oilPaintEffect(canvas, radius, intensity) {
    var width = canvas.width,
        height = canvas.height,
        imgData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, width, height),
        pixData = imgData.data,
        destCanvas = document.createElement("canvas"),
        dCtx = destCanvas.getContext("2d"),
        pixelIntensityCount = [];

    destCanvas.width = width;
    destCanvas.height = height;

    // for demo purposes, remove this to modify the original canvas
    document.body.appendChild(destCanvas);

    var destImageData = dCtx.createImageData(width, height),
        destPixData = destImageData.data,
        intensityLUT = [],
        rgbLUT = [];

    for (var y = 0; y < height; y++) {
        intensityLUT[y] = [];
        rgbLUT[y] = [];
        for (var x = 0; x < width; x++) {
            var idx = (y * width + x) * 4,
                r = pixData[idx],
                g = pixData[idx + 1],
                b = pixData[idx + 2],
                avg = (r + g + b) / 3;

            intensityLUT[y][x] = Math.round((avg * intensity) / 255);
            rgbLUT[y][x] = {
                r: r,
                g: g,
                b: b
            };
        }
    }


    for (y = 0; y < height; y++) {
        for (x = 0; x < width; x++) {

            pixelIntensityCount = [];

            // Find intensities of nearest pixels within radius.
            for (var yy = -radius; yy <= radius; yy++) {
                for (var xx = -radius; xx <= radius; xx++) {
                    if (y + yy > 0 && y + yy < height && x + xx > 0 && x + xx < width) {
                        var intensityVal = intensityLUT[y + yy][x + xx];

                        if (!pixelIntensityCount[intensityVal]) {
                            pixelIntensityCount[intensityVal] = {
                                val: 1,
                                r: rgbLUT[y + yy][x + xx].r,
                                g: rgbLUT[y + yy][x + xx].g,
                                b: rgbLUT[y + yy][x + xx].b
                            }
                        } else {
                            pixelIntensityCount[intensityVal].val++;
                            pixelIntensityCount[intensityVal].r += rgbLUT[y + yy][x + xx].r;
                            pixelIntensityCount[intensityVal].g += rgbLUT[y + yy][x + xx].g;
                            pixelIntensityCount[intensityVal].b += rgbLUT[y + yy][x + xx].b;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            pixelIntensityCount.sort(function (a, b) {
                return b.val - a.val;
            });

            var curMax = pixelIntensityCount[0].val,
                dIdx = (y * width + x) * 4;

            destPixData[dIdx] = ~~ (pixelIntensityCount[0].r / curMax);
            destPixData[dIdx + 1] = ~~ (pixelIntensityCount[0].g / curMax);
            destPixData[dIdx + 2] = ~~ (pixelIntensityCount[0].b / curMax);
            destPixData[dIdx + 3] = 255;
        }
    }

    // change this to ctx to instead put the data on the original canvas
    dCtx.putImageData(destImageData, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: Hats off! This could be the first painting effect in javascript. I think that controls in your codepen are not working, however I was able to play with the values in the code. The logic is very good. You should consider wrapping this a little and make it available for the public :)

Comment: @FrancescoFrapporti thanks will definitely post the code out there, made a github repo today just havent updated it yet. In the codepen example make sure to hit the button that says "effect" (I should probably name that better). Another cool side effect is if you set intensity to 0, it becomes a blur filter.

Comment: Ah, feel so dumb! Looking forward for the repo.

Comment: @FrancescoFrapporti haha no problem it was due to my poor naming of the button. I always get obsessive over these pieces of code. Just updated it so the filtered image isn't smaller than the original (another improvement over the original authors article)

Comment: Do effects like this need to be on canvas, or can they be applied to a simple html img element?

Comment: @kojow7 Have to be on canvas, you get direct access to the pixel buffer via canvas, not with an image element though.

Answer (score 1):

Paste a demo of [@Loktar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24223242/10251345) here for someone looking for this algorithm.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"),
    img = new Image(),
    effectEl = document.getElementById("effect"),
    settings = {
      radius : 4,
      intensity : 25,
      ApplyFilter : function(){
         doOilPaintEffect();
      }
    }

img.addEventListener('load', function () {
    // reduced the size by half for pen and performance.
    canvas.width = (this.width/2);
    canvas.height = (this.height/2);
    ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    doOilPaintEffect();
});

img.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";
img.src = "https://codropspz-tympanus.netdna-ssl.com/codrops/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/ImageTechniques.jpg";

var gui = new dat.GUI();
gui.add(settings, 'intensity');
gui.add(settings, 'radius');
gui.add(settings, 'ApplyFilter');

function doOilPaintEffect(){
  oilPaintEffect(canvas, settings.radius, settings.intensity);
}

function oilPaintEffect(canvas, radius, intensity) {
    var width = canvas.width,
        height = canvas.height,
        imgData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, width, height),
        pixData = imgData.data,
        // change to createElement getting added element just for the demo
        destCanvas = document.getElementById("dest-canvas"),
        dCtx = destCanvas.getContext("2d"),
        pixelIntensityCount = [];
    
    destCanvas.width = width;
    destCanvas.height = height;
    
    var destImageData = dCtx.createImageData(width, height),
        destPixData = destImageData.data,
        intensityLUT = [],
        rgbLUT = [];
    
    for (var y = 0; y < height; y++) {
        intensityLUT[y] = [];
        rgbLUT[y] = [];
        for (var x = 0; x < width; x++) {
            var idx = (y * width + x) * 4,
                r = pixData[idx],
                g = pixData[idx + 1],
                b = pixData[idx + 2],
                avg = (r + g + b) / 3;
            
            intensityLUT[y][x] = Math.round((avg * intensity) / 255);
            rgbLUT[y][x] = {
                r: r,
                g: g,
                b: b
            };
        }
    }
    
    
    for (y = 0; y < height; y++) {
        for (x = 0; x < width; x++) {
            pixelIntensityCount = [];
            
            // Find intensities of nearest pixels within radius.
            for (var yy = -radius; yy <= radius; yy++) {
                for (var xx = -radius; xx <= radius; xx++) {
                  if (y + yy > 0 && y + yy < height && x + xx > 0 && x + xx < width) {
                      var intensityVal = intensityLUT[y + yy][x + xx];

                      if (!pixelIntensityCount[intensityVal]) {
                          pixelIntensityCount[intensityVal] = {
                              val: 1,
                              r: rgbLUT[y + yy][x + xx].r,
                              g: rgbLUT[y + yy][x + xx].g,
                              b: rgbLUT[y + yy][x + xx].b
                          }
                      } else {
                          pixelIntensityCount[intensityVal].val++;
                          pixelIntensityCount[intensityVal].r += rgbLUT[y + yy][x + xx].r;
                          pixelIntensityCount[intensityVal].g += rgbLUT[y + yy][x + xx].g;
                          pixelIntensityCount[intensityVal].b += rgbLUT[y + yy][x + xx].b;
                      }
                  }
                }
            }
            
            pixelIntensityCount.sort(function (a, b) {
                return b.val - a.val;
            });
            
            var curMax = pixelIntensityCount[0].val,
                dIdx = (y * width + x) * 4;
            
            destPixData[dIdx] = ~~ (pixelIntensityCount[0].r / curMax);
            destPixData[dIdx + 1] = ~~ (pixelIntensityCount[0].g / curMax);
            destPixData[dIdx + 2] = ~~ (pixelIntensityCount[0].b / curMax);
            destPixData[dIdx + 3] = 255;
        }
    }
    
    // change this to ctx to instead put the data on the original canvas
    dCtx.putImageData(destImageData, 0, 0);
}
```

```css
body{text-align:center;background:#ececec;font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif}
section{display:inline-block}
canvas{border:1px solid #000}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dat-gui/0.5/dat.gui.min.js"></script>
<section>
  <h2>Original</h2>
  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
</section>
<section>
  <h2>Oil Painting Effect</h2>
   <canvas id="dest-canvas"></canvas>
</section>
```