# Is in sharp js a similar function like imagemagick OilPaint filter for smoothing edges?

Tags: imagemagick, sharp, imagefilter

I use the image processing sharp-js. In the past I used imagemagick. There is a nice function OilPaint for smoothing edges. i.e. in perl

```
 $error = $image->[0]->OilPaint( radius => 0 )
```

Now I want migrate from perl + imagemagick to node + sharp-js.

How can I smooth edges in sharp-js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are none filter in sharpjs like OilPaint in imagemagik. But its no problem use sharp-js and graphicsmagick (it use imagemagik) in combination i.e.

```
await sharp("cat.png")
    .extract({
      left: ankerX,
      top: ankerY,
      width: sizeX,
      height: sizeY,
    })
    .toFile("cat_section.png");

await gm("cat_section.png")
    .paint(1)
    .write("cat_section_oil.png", function (err) {
      if (err) console.log(err);
      console.log("Oil Done!");
    });
```

If you want, you can easy write your own filter. Some useful code + instruction you find here [Apply a Oil Paint/Sketch effect to a photo using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24223242/1514029)